# Is there a way to check if a text or image is already rendered in the screen in IE11 using VBScript or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, internet-explorer-11

I got an intermittent problem on IE11 emulating IE8. The texts and some images are not displayed, when I change from page to another page, but when I checked the DOM by Inspecting elements in IE11, it is already loaded. Is there a way to check if a text or image is rendered on screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someId').length
```

if length = 1 the element is found in page.
if length = 0 the element is not found in page.

Comment: this of course is quite elegant, but it only checks if the element has been loaded into the DOM, but not if it's actually rendered,

Answer (score 0):

Well, the element might exist in theory in the DOM, but to really check if it has been rendered on screen, I can only think of the hacky solution of wrapping it inside a div, and check if said div has a width greater than 0.
This should only happen once the element has been rendered, but results may vary.

Here is a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/rtz4becg/

I included the "not loaded" check in the  of the document, so it would give us a negative answer; and the true checking function on load.
I had to set the timeout to force an asynchronous check, otherwise the document might only update after the function return of `$(document).ready()`, which will be too late for us.

JS:

```
var w = $(".checkinside").width();
if (w > 0) {
    alert("I was rendered and have a width greater than 0: " + w);
} else {
    alert("I was not rendered yet.");
}

function checkload(){
        $(".checkinside").each(function () {
        var w = $(this).width();
        if (w > 0) {
            alert("I was rendered and have a width greater than 0: " + w);
        } else {
            alert("I was not rendered yet.");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(checkload, 10);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checkinside">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024" id="my-image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkinside {
    display:table;
    width:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Ben Philipp, I've tried your suggestion. That was a good idea but when I implemented it on VBScript, intermittently, the text is not displayed even if the width is not zero. Here is some codes to show how I implemented it.

VBScript:

```
msgBox someHtmlID.offsetWidth 'message box outputs 0
someHtmlID.innerHtml = "Text" 'loads "Text" on DOM
'some codes here
msgBox someHtmlID.innerHtml   'message box outputs Text
msgBox someHtmlID.offsetWidth 'message box outputs 27
```

Is the idea the same?

Comment: Make sure you perform the check asynchronously, since the DOM changes might only be rendered after a return... Depending on where and when something is supposed to happen after the element is rendered, you might succeed using a timed function